# How to enable the HTTPS under native provider in network setting of eclipse in a proxy environment

Tags: eclipse, networking, https, native

My system is behind a proxy server,
The vm argument "-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4" is given in the eclipse.ini file to support the native provider.
When i use native network provider,i could not use HTTPS.
I need to use HTTPS with native provider in the network settings

When i tried removing the "-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4" from eclipse.ini ,
Still i was not able to use https in  help->install new software and link i used is "https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.7"

is there any way to enable the HTTPS under native provider network settings in eclipse when used in a proxy environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the Preferences (Preferences > General > Network Connection) choose Native as active provider.

Furthermore add something like:

```
-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
-Dhttp.proxyPort=
-Dhttp.proxyHost=
-Dhttp.proxyUser=
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
```

to the eclipse.ini. Or try it with:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient
```